# Regular expression match multiple <images> tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match the following  tag multiple times.

At the moment i have this: `<img[\w\W]+\/?>`, but instead of pick up three times, i find the image as a whole things because it match start with '', is there anyway i can match them individually three times?

```
<img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/jetty-road-baby.jpeg" alt="Jetty" width="100" height="100" />asdasd

test

<img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/jetty-road-baby.jpeg" alt="Jetty" width="100" height="100" />

test

<img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/jetty-road-baby.jpeg" alt="Jetty" width="100" height="100" />
```

Cheers
Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Possessive [Quantifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers) to fix it

```
/<img[\w\W]+?\/?>/g
```

The `?` after `+` makes the `+` a non-greedy quantifier, ie as soon as a `>` is found it stops the search else it will continue the search till the last `>` is found

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark
- [lazy-mode](http://javascript.info/tutorial/greedy-and-lazy#lazy-mode)

---

You can also try `/<img[^>]*\/?>/g` - where we try to find char sequances starting with `<img` followed by any number of characters other than `>` followed by `/`(optional) and `>`.

---

Caution: Regular expression based processing of html can be buggy like in the above case an attribute of the image can have `>` in it which will break our regex

Comment: @bluebill1049 another way could be `/<img[^>]*\/?>/g`